# Which Language to target on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, python, ubuntu, mono

I'm a c# programmer by trade and looking to move my wares over to Ubuntu as a business concern. I have some experience of Python and like it a lot. My question is, as a developer which would be the best language to use when targeting ubuntu Mono c# or python as a commercial concern.

please note that I am not interested in the technical aspects but strictly the commercials of where Ubuntu is heading, I see that there is a lot of work done within using Python and thinking that maybe with the whole Mono issue of who "might" purchase them.

Comment: So you are trying to decide which language you should use but you are not interested in the technical aspects? That does not make sence IMHO

Comment: Technically, nope I have used both languages for quite some time and know about the technical issues of each. I don't need answers regarding how 'cool' this is and how 'bad' such and such is. I am more interested in the commercials.

Comment: OK, now I understand. Maybe you should edit your question.

Comment: If you are worried about the business logistics, you would switch to Qt/C++ or Java since they've been around for quite some time now. Both of those platforms are mature on Linux and will continue to be. Neither had any huge changes recently (Qt switched to 4.0 5 years ago, but even 3.0 technology works; it is deprecated). Mono has always been playing catch-up and i've seen tons of projects like mono bite the dust. Python had a huge change 2 years ago with 3.0 that broke a lot in 2.*, and I would expect another change coming in the next couple years (GIL is still in 3.0 for instance). My $0.02

Comment: I did think about Java until Oracle stepped in.

Comment: I have just taken a look at the Mono Licence. It looks ok. But where would the product go say if Novel got bought by a hacksaw outfit.

Comment: I like python a lot, I like the philosophy. The GIL does concern me, but there are work arounds and most tasks I look at can be done using Co-routines. Mono would be my natural root, however a leap of faith from one commercial entity (Microsoft) into the arms of the next suitor of Novel does leave me a little worried, since I am trying to move into a free development environment and software as a means to an ends instead of the ends itself.

Comment: What kind of "business concern"?  That seems to be the crux of the argument.  Who would your customers be?

Comment: My concern is one of operating without paying fees to the shoulders of giants that I am using to leverage my hefty weight upon, I will contribute to the industry in open source solutions, whilst providing paid for services for my time and labour to people who require such help in realising their dreams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Python and Mono are installed by default on recent Ubuntu, and will [likely continue to be](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2009-June/000584.html) for the foreseeable future.

Mono is removable since it is currently only used by a few desktop apps. Python is not reasonably removable as a lot of core scripts and GNOME tools depend on it. (The same is true of Perl.)

The [popularity contest](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) shows Python to be installed somewhat more often than Mono but both are widespread:

```
21    python-minimal  1584305 182870 1381149 20211    75 (Matthias Klose)   
577   mono-gac        1403534  25795 1323328 54159   252 (Debian Mono Group)
```

As for commercial potential, it's difficult to say without any idea what sector you might be working in. If you are targeting servers, especially running older versions of Ubuntu, Mono will be less widespread. If you are selling simple consumer desktop apps... well, it has yet to be demonstrated that there is really a market for this!

Comment: Since the question is about the commercial perspective here, does it really matter how popular these technologies are? And what prevents mono to be included with the product?

Comment: It's a barometer of acceptance amongst Ubuntu users; without any more details as to who the target market are, that's about all we've got to go on. You wouldn't bundle Mono with an app (that'd be a recipe for nasty conflicts), but you could certainly mark it as a dependency. Would Ubuntu users consider the implementation language as a deal-breaker? I'd say in general no, though naturally there are a few zealots who consider Mono MS-spawned ‘evil’.

Comment: I think that Microsoft have done a bang up job of .net and its a fine fine product, just a shame about the OS. Why on earth are people still stupid enough to pay for an OS when there are so many great free ones out there. Hence my move.

Comment: Sad to hear people call others stupid only because they choose differently. Then why should we buy your product? Or perhaps it is free? Then why should we be stupid enough to support whatever you are making a living out of?

Comment: @Peter, The General public are ignorant to the fact that there are viable alternatives to paying cash. The whole branding marketing machine clouds the playing field, solutions are based on visibility on the open market as opposed to best in class. I provide solutions as a service, hey its a philosophical argument but one I feel I very much have the higher ground on :)

Comment: The GP should not be paying for such done and done things as OS, but for the services that can be provided to suit their real needs.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say much about the market for Ubuntu. And since business is your primary concern, the programming language is, as you say yourself, secondary. I would say that in any business, choose the language and tools that solves the business problem most effectively. When release comes do your end users really care?

That said, if you can do it with Mono/C# I would encourage you to do so since you already have C# and .Net experience. But knowing a second language and development environment will only make you stronger.

Comment: I got issues with Mono, mainly in the aquisition stakes of who might be the owner, we have already seen Java go to the Larry camp, who is to say that Mono won't go the same way.

Comment: I hear that Mono have been looking for Suitors.